# Every element of my page is behaving as the link my last button holds

Tags: html, css, button, hyperlink

I'm working on a portfolio, and everything is fine, except every text element is behaving as the link in my last button. This is true of all other pages of content as well, and applies in other areas to both images and text. Here is the html for the page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/styles2.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Timmana" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
     <button class="btn photo"><a href="http://students.purchase.edu/MEGAN.STACEY/advanced/photo.html">Photo</button>
<button class="btn video"><a href="http://students.purchase.edu/MEGAN.STACEY/advanced/video.html">Video</button>
<button class="btn audio"><a href="http://students.purchase.edu/MEGAN.STACEY/advanced/audio.html">Audio</button>
<button class="btn design"><a href="http://students.purchase.edu/MEGAN.STACEY/advanced/design.html">Design</button>
<button class="btn essays"><a href="http://students.purchase.edu/MEGAN.STACEY/advanced/essays.html">Essays</button>
<button class="btn other"><a href="http://students.purchase.edu/MEGAN.STACEY/advanced/other.html">Other</button>
<button class="btn about"><a href="http://students.purchase.edu/MEGAN.STACEY/advanced/about.html">About</button>
<p>
    <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/257547177" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </p>
    <p>Wait, Wait, Wait: A response to the Disruption prompt in Video Art 1</p>
    <p> Conception, Direction, Filming, Editing by Megan Stacey. Performers include Calliope Pinaparker and Autumn Blazon-Brown.</p>
<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/254261488" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
<p>Two Truths and a Lie: A response to the Questionarre prompt in Video Art 1
</p>
<p>Conception, Writing, Direction, Editing, and Performance by Megan Stacey. Filming and Additional Editing by Jewel Slade.</p>
<p>
    <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/259502039" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
<p>Performance Compilation 1: A series of experiments in solo performance, video, and audio</p>
<p>Conceptualized, performed, and edited by Megan Stacey</p>
</p>
<p><iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/251061619" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe></p>
<p>
<p>
    Your Hair Got In My Eye Fuck Off: A Collaboration with the Theatrical Company, the Dream Factory
</p>
<p> Conception, Filming, and Editing by Megan Stacey. Music: "The Philosopher" by John Cale. 
</p> <p> Performers include Autumn Blazon Brown, Harmony Fiori, Adam Browne, and Romey Drabek</p>

</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

And here is my referenced style sheet, if that may be a problem:

.wrapper {

```
    text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
}

p {
    color: black;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
}

a:link {

    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:visited {

    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:active {

    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.btn {
    border: none;
    background-color: inherit;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    font-size: 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    transition-duration: 1s;
    font-family: 'Timmana', sans-serif;
}

/* Green */
.photo {
    color: black;
}

.photo:hover {
    background-color: #ff0000;
    color: white;
}

/* Blue */
.video {
    color: black;
}

.video:hover {
    background: #e60000;
    color: white;
}

/* Orange */
.audio {
    color: black;
}

.audio:hover {
    background: #cc0000;
    color: white;
}

/* Red */
.design {
    color: black;
}

.design:hover {
    background: #b30000;
    color: white;
}

/* Gray */
.essays {
    color: black;
}

.essays:hover {
    background: #990000;
    color: white;
}

.other {
    color: black;
}

.other:hover {
    background: #800000;
    color: white;
}

.about {
    color: black;
}

.about:hover {
    background: #660000;
    color: white;
```

Comment: seriously .. a right click/inspect element and you will ses what's wrong

Comment: I have flagged it as typo @TemaniAfif

Answer (score 0):

That's because you haven't closed any of your anchor tags

Comment: this is correct but i think better flag question as Typo error ... not sure this deserve an answer and being archived for futur purpose..

Answer (score -1):

Woah!!!
You Froget to close all anchor tag.Anchor tag should be used as

```
<a href="www.site.com" > your text here </a>
```

Comment: can you tell me what is the purpose of adding the same answer already provided twice ?